# why manual scrolling stop when i added auto scrolling in my page query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am facing one problem .Actually I am working with socket programming in which I am getting data from server after a reqular interval of time.In beginning I am able to scroll my div when data is coming from server .But I add auto scroll code it start auto scrolling and stop manual scrolling.I will explain more i detail When data come from server I save that data in html or text file .When i click button for review it only show data upto the height of div..so i can solve problem with me,,

Here is css..!!

```
div.left, div.right {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
#realTimeContents {
    overflow - y: scroll;
}
```

Hers is my html

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="sliderContend_h" style="display: none; padding-top:10px;">
    <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="15" min="15" max="25" class="slider_h" data-highlight="true" />
</div>
<img src="img/ajax_loader_blue_512.gif" id="loadingImg" style='vertical-align: middle  ;margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 200px; visibility:visible;'>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="realTimeContents" class="left realtimeContend_h" style="width:100%;height:1100px;"></div>
        <!--div id="realTimeContents" class=" right realtimeContend_h">
                             </div-->
        <div class="cursor" style="font-size:23px;">|</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js..

```
  function nativePluginResultHandler(result) {

      var isappend = window.localStorage.getItem("isAppendButtonClick");
      if (isappend == 'true') {
          $('#loadingImg').hide();
          var currentTime = new Date()
          var hours = currentTime.getHours()
          var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

          if (minutes < 10) {
              minutes = "0" + minutes
          }
          var lines = result.split('<br/>');
          $.each(lines, function () {
              var text = "<span style='margin-left: 50px;'>" + this + "</span>";
              $('#realTimeContents').append("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b> " + text + "<br/>");
          });
          var elem = document.getElementById('realTimeContents');
          elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
          // $('#realTimeContents').prepend('<p>'+result+'</p>');
          console.log(result + "************naveen***************");
          //  $('#realTimeContents' ).append('<p>'+result+'</p>');
      }

  }
```

How to start scrolling (manually  when user scroll that actually div is not responded.It stand  straight without any change state

Comment: how to add iscroll in div?

Comment: I think problem is that height:1100px; I am fixing the height of that div that why it start auto scrolling but remove scrolling when user come to see the text on this div he is able to see only upto height

Comment: actually I am getting response from server that why i am not able to show you? I am hitting the server of same network ..:(

Comment: I explain my problem my auto scrolling is working fine actually I have data in text file or in html file .And At the time of review I read the text file .I am able to see unto 1100 px height .And I am not able to scroll that..may i use scroll?

Comment: Please use jsfiddle with some raw data to depict your problem.I am not understanding you.

Comment: ok ..i Will try my best ..can you please tell me how to remove height dynamically .Actually I am thinking the if user click review button I remove this height..?

Comment: Use '$('#someDiv').css("height", ""); 
$('#someDiv').css("height", null);' other way set height to 'auto'

Comment: I understand the problem while using auto scrolling we use static height it scroll automatically but not not manually because But when i remove this height using this your method before review the data it scroll .Is it any way to scull manually and automatically?

Comment: other approach  to scroll automatically without using constant height if the page end it start vertical scrolling?

Comment: did you try setting overflow:auto? also set div position to absolute

Comment: Not work..is this possible to use iscroller library here?